# UIViewController released before its view has been closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK and using **ARC**.

I do this to show a `UIViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)showMyObjectsMenu:(id)sender
{
    MyObjectsMenuViewController* myObjectsController = [[MyObjectsMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyObjectsMenuViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.view addSubview:myObjectsController.view];
}
```

But this is wrong because the `myObjectsController` is released at the of the method `- (IBAction)showMyObjectsMenu:(id)sender`.

**How can I do to show a `viewcontroller` on the right way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either add the controller as a child view controller (iOS 5.0+) or otherwise store it in an instance variable somewhere.  The same as any other variable that needs longer storage.

Comment: How can I add the controller as a child view controller?

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise for you to discover :).  I will say that it only works on other `UIViewController` objects though, so check the documentation for that class.